# Detection of dangling modifier

Tags: errors

Sentence that needs correction :

> "***For building*** vocabulary skills, students should try to speak and write new words in appropriate contexts, rather than merely memorizing definitions".

How is "for building" a dangling modifier?

Comment: Hello, Ben. If you explain what you understand by a 'dangling modifier' and give a few examples (there are plenty of grammar sites dealing with this topic), perhaps someone will give you an answer. Perhaps you will see it for yourself!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  This is a dangling modifier; "Having finished the assignment, the TV was turned on." Is my sentence a dangling modifier as skills = students? Skills can't be compared to students.

Comment: Your (original) example is a bit trickier. With the second example, the modifier 'Having finished the assignment(,)' is placed just before 'the TV'. The TV obviously hasn't finished the assignment, so the participial clause (the modifier) shouldn't be placed just before it. The same argument could be made for 'For building vocabulary skills' and 'students', though this is really a bit pedantic. Switching to 'In order to build their vocabulary skills,' should keep everybody happy.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Anything wrong with, "To build vocabulary skills, students should . . ."? Just wondering. Don

Comment: @rhetorician: It's short for 'In order to build vocabulary skills'; I'd have no problem with it. Some might argue it could be construed as the 'to-infinitive' meaning 'made/supplied for the purpose of' as in 'This tool is to get stones out of horses' hooves', but I'd leave the course if they were my tutors.

Answer (score 2):

Position is crucial in the English language. Perhaps the two following examples from two different kinds of modifying issues will help you discover an answer to your question.

Example of a dangling modifier:
Running fast as possible, victory was assured.

**Note** that the modifying phrase at the beginning (often the case in dangling modifiers) is followed directly by something that can not actually do the running. Such a sentence must be recast. Running fast as possible, Bob felt that victory was assured.

Example of a misplaced modifier:
High on the hill, I saw the lovely cows.

**Note** that the modifying phrase High on the hill is followed by "I". This means that the "I" is high on the hill. If that is the intent (i.e. that the "I" is indeed HIGH on the hill, all is well. If the intent is that the "I" observes "cows" high on that hill, then you have a misplaced modifier. To repair this problem, the modifying phrase high on the hill should follow "cows". I saw the lovely cows high on the hill.

The problem is one of clarity of meaning. The misplaced modifier fix here does not remove some ambiguities.

Still position is all!
Consider reading Frances Yates' tale at the opening of *The Art of Memory* to add some depth to this investigation, which I'll call "Every idea in its place." In the story set in ancient Rome, a heavy ceiling falls on diners lying on divans around a long dais. Afterwards, their relatives could not figure out who the individuals were (too mangled to identify) so each might be given proper burial. The Art of memory was born thereby, as the poet (giving the banquet recital--but rescued from the others' fate in the nick of time) revealed their true identities. He accomplished this through his recollection of the exact location where each of his former friends was reclining when they were enjoying their banquet.

Post Script: Castor and Pollux were the ones who rescued the poet with the great gift!